# How can I change text in capitals to proper sentence case in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

"IF I WRITE THIS IN EXCEL IN CAPITAL LETTERS", I want to be able to change this to "If I write this in excel in capital letters" using a formula.

What formula would I need to use to achieve this?

Comment: Your title and tags are misleading. Are you asking how to do this in both Excel AND Word?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a formula for proper capitalization of a sentence. You would have to use both the [UPPER](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/upper-HP005209327.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) and [LOWER](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lower-HP005209167.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) functions to achieve what you want with some string manipulation. For example:

```
= UPPER(LEFT(A1)) & LOWER(MID(A1, 2, LEN(A1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, but because  the sentence is already in upper case, you can go shorter.

=left(A1) & lower(right(A1,len(A1)-1))